# Can I use the same SSH key in different places?

Tags: ssh

I'm using WSL2 and I came across something related to SSH. I created an SSH key inside my Ubuntu and used it on GitHub, and then I needed to use an SSH key inside Google Cloud too; I tried to create another key with another name, but I had problem with "permission denied (publickey)" when I tried to connect to that server. I tried several things but nothing worked, so I used the same key I generated to use on GitHub and it worked! I would like to know if there is any problem in doing this? Should I generate a separate key for each thing? Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same key for multiple remote systems. The private key is never shared with the service you log in to, so authenticating towards Github will not allow Github to impersonate you.

What you *should* not do is to use the same private key on multiple machines - if you loose one machine you'll have to replace everything. One private-public key pair per machine, so you only have to revoke access to one keypair.